# How can I insert dynamic drop-down list into dynamic tag?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I've tried to make dynamic drop-down list but it doesn't work.

[Start-up screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsZvo.jpg)

When I click 'Add Row' button, then it changes like this.

[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u424H.jpg)

I really wanna change that added drop-down list like the first list, but there is no data.

Here is the code.

```
    <button id='btn-add-row'>Add Row</button>
    <button id='btn-delete-row'>Delete Row</button>
       <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script>
        $('#btn-add-row').click(function() {
          $('#mytable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox"><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td><td></td><td><select id="slist"></select></td><td></td></tr>');
      });
        $('#btn-delete-row').click(function() {
          $('#mytable > tbody:last > tr:last').remove();
          $('#mytable > tbody:last > tr:last').remove();
       });

      setattr();

      function setattr(){
          var myobject = {
            ValueA : 'Text A',
            ValueB : 'Text B',
            ValueC : 'Text C'
        };

        var select = document.getElementById("slist");
        for(index in myobject) {
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(myobject[index], index);
        }

        if(select.options.length > 0) {
          //  window.alert("Text: " + select.options[select.selectedIndex].text + "\nValue: " + select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
        }
        else {
            window.alert("Select box is empty");
        }
      }
      </script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is using DOM method and posted to [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/2qcrL2bb/).

```
var myTable=document.getElementById("mytable");
$('#btn-add-row').click(function() {
 row=mytable.insertRow(mytable.rows.length);
cell=row.insertCell(row.length);
cell=row.insertCell(row.length);
cell=row.insertCell(row.length);
dropDownBox=document.createElement("select");
buildDropDownBox(dropDownBox);
cell.appendChild(dropDownBox);
cell=row.insertCell(row.length);
});
$('#btn-delete-row').click(function() {
 myTable.deleteRow(mytable.rows.length-1);
});
function buildDropDownBox(select)
{
  var myobject = {
        ValueA : 'Text A',
        ValueB : 'Text B',
        ValueC : 'Text C'
    };
    for(index in myobject) {
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(myobject[index], index);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i need to add textarea row before the drop-down list's, so i modify that code now =)